# Listview: переход по элементам

Tags: android, listview, java, сортировка

Доброго времени суток! 
Нужна помощь в реализации нажатия на элемент лист вью. Необходимо присвоить каждому в списке элементу переход на разные активити.
Я попробовал реализовать следующим способом, но при осуществления поиска по элементам, первый найденный элемент тоже переходит на ту активити, которая задана для первого элемента массива, как это исправить?
Код

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                        View arg1, int position, long arg3)
     {
         switch (position) {
             case 0:
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), bbns.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
         }        
     }   });
}
```

Может можно как-то через `tag` реализовать это, если можно то как?

Comment: можно поподробнее, не совсем понял в чем проблема, код на первый взгляд рабочий

Comment: да, можете через tag сделать, это все. подробней могу рассказать, если скажите как у вас разделяются activity

Comment: gadfil, если поподробнее, то есть поле для ввода текста, снизу массив, после ввода текста фильтруется массив и остаются необходимые результаты. Первое, что выведет, не зависимо от того что это, все равно будет переходить не на ту активити что надо, а на ту, у которой прописана позиция 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно придумать множество способов реализации данной функциональности , вот по быстрому набрасал c использованием тегов:
Это код главной активити (не забудьте создать xml layout со списком )

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
{
    private static Map<String, Class<? extends Activity>> activityRegistry = new HashMap<String, Class<? extends Activity>>();
    static
    {
        activityRegistry.put("item1", FirstActivity.class);
        activityRegistry.put("item2", SecondActivity.class);
        activityRegistry.put("item3", ThirdActivity.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_main_activity);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.container);
        list.setAdapter(new ActivityAdapter(this, activityRegistry.keySet().toArray(new String[] {})));
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View self, int position, long arg3)
    {
        Class<? extends Activity> newActivityClass = activityRegistry.get(((ViewHolder) self.getTag()).key);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, newActivityClass);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    class ActivityAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private String[] activityItems;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public ActivityAdapter(Context context, String[] activityItems)
        {
            super();
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.activityItems = activityItems;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return activityItems.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int id)
        {
            return activityItems[id];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int id)
        {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int posituon, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null)
            {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.vw_item, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
            else
            {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.key = activityItems[posituon];
            holder.text.setText(holder.key);

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder
        {
            TextView text;
            String key;
        }
    }

}
```

и простенько для item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Да и если вы используете шерлок или андроид со 2 версии то конечно же будут не просто Activity, а SherlockFragmentActivity и FragmentActivity соответственно

Comment: С чем это может быть связано?

Multiple markers at this line
 - ViewHolder cannot be resolved 
  to a type
 - ViewHolder cannot be resolved 
  to a type

Comment: Скорее всего Вы обращаетесь к внутреннему класу ViewHolder из места где он не может быть видимым, например из другой активити. ну если это так уж нужно, то  можно конечно вынести ViewHolder в отдельный класс но это не айс, если предоставите кусок кода откуда вы хотите достучаться до класса то я смогу найти правильное решение

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                        View arg1, int position, long arg3)
   {Intent intent =null;
        switch (Integer.parseInt(arg1.getTag().toString())) 
        {
        case 0:
            intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SomeClass.class);break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SomeClass.class);break;

        }        
startActivity(intent);
        });

}
```